# Padding around objects

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working with the new SwiftUI.

If I want to do something simple like stick two square blocks next to each other with no space between, my natural tendency would be to do set the padding to 0 around the images, but that doesn't work.

I can accomplish what I want by using a .offset() modifier but that seems to be "doing it the wrong way".  I'm wondering if Apple assumes they will figure out the padding even if you specify you don't want any?  Hoping someone knows how it is designed to work properly and I"m just missing the right modifier or modifier syntax.

Tried using the modifier .padding(.all,0) and the two Images still have some space between them.

```
 HStack {
        Image(systemName: "faceid").padding(.all,0)
        Image(systemName: "faceid").padding(.all,0)         
       }
```

Comment: Did the proposed solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the spacing in your `HStack` to 0.
It should look like this:

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
       Image(systemName: "faceid")
       Image(systemName: "faceid")
}
```

Comment: Question: It worked and I think I understand but could you explain "how" you knew and why it works that way?

Comment: Sorry; new to this.  I think I fixed that?

Comment: I had an intuition about it possibly being a parameter in the `HStack` so I looked at the `HStack` [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/hstack/3269212-init) and saw that spacing was an option so I tried it on XCode and it worked. Simply put, if you provide a spacing the `HStack` uses that if you don’t it choses one for you.

Comment: Thank you sir!  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It’s the spacing on HStack that you need to change:

```
HStack(spacing: 0)
```